# Problem with installing plugin in Audacity

Tags: plugins, audacity

I edit my songs in Audacity on my ubuntu 18.04 computer. Recently i downloaded [GSNAP plugin](https://www.gvst.co.uk/gsnap.htm)(file extension : .so) and followed [this article](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/installing_effect_generator_and_analyzer_plug_ins_on_linux.html#vst_install) to install it. I should log in with root to edit the **plug-ins** folder. I entered `sudo -i` for logging in as root but I wasn't able to place the GVST plugin file into the PLUG-INS folder.

I also tried to do it completely in COMMAND LINE, but this was the result[image: error]

Comment: Can you give more details? What happened when you tried to place the plug-in into the folder? How did you move it (using what commands)? Did any error messages show, and what did they say?

Comment: I logged into root and dragged the file into the folder. It didn't move there (Like I don't have the access to edit the folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I believe I understand the issue.  See, Linux is designed as a multi-user server operating system.  That means it is intended to allow many sessions of different users to exist at once.  When you signed in as root using by issuing the `sudo -i` command in a terminal, it didn't give your main user session any additional privileges.  To Linux, when you opened the terminal window (most likely by opening the Terminal application), you created a new session of yourself.  The `sudo -i` command then elevated that session to root privileges, but it didn't elevate the privileges of the existing GUI session.  Thus, when you tried to move the file around in the GUI session, you didn't have the permissions to do so, since that was only granted to your terminal session.

The solution is fairly simple: either carry out the entire task in the terminal, or use a different target location.  I would recommend the latter.  Thus, instead of trying to move the plug-in into `/usr/lib/vst/` (which isn't a terribly good idea anyways: dpkg is designed to have exclusive control over that folder), copy it into `~/.vst`.  In other words, create a new directory in your home folder called `.vst`, and copy the plugin file into that.  This doesn't require root permissions, won't anger dpkg and apt, and can be done from the GUI.

Comment: But i can't find this plugin when i go to find the plugins option in AUDACITY

Comment: I tried doing the entire process in command line, I edited the question to include the screenshot

Comment: It looks like you installed Audacity via a Snap package.  I don't think it will be very easy (if its even possible) to then add a plugin.  I would recommend reinstalling audacity directly from the Ubuntu archive (via 'sudo apt install audacity'), and then trying again.